# Why would a customer's IP address not show on orders sometimes?

Tags: admin, customer

In the Dashboard: System > Configuration > Sales > Sales...

I have "Hide Customer IP: No"

and this means the customers IP is shown on orders and invoices, etc...

This works on almost every order, but a couple orders just don't show an IP at all. This is very rare, and maybe 1 out of every 100 orders don't show an IP.

Well, what would cause this? I was asked why this is, but I just didn't have an answer, and now I'm curious.

Thanks all.

Comment: If you look up the order in BE, can you see the customer IP there? Was it saved correctly?

Comment: Hey, what does BE stand for?

Comment: Backend, sorry!

Comment: Maybe the order was created manually?

Comment: If an order is place by an Admin user, then the ip address field will be blank

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably the order was made from the back-end.
The ip address on the order comes from the quote.
in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml` there is this:

```
<config>
...
    <global>
    ...
        <fieldsets>
        ...
            <sales_convert_quote>
                <remote_ip>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </remote_ip> 
                ...
            </sales_convert_quote>
        ...
        </fieldsets>
    ...
    </global> 
...
</config>
```

The IP address on the quote is set in `Mage_Checkout_Model_Session::getQuote()`

```
if ($remoteAddr = Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr()) {
    $this->_quote->setRemoteIp($remoteAddr);
    $xForwardIp = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    $this->_quote->setXForwardedFor($xForwardIp);
}
```

When creating an order from the backend `Mage_Checkout_Model_Session` is not used. Instead `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Session_Quote` is used and there is no trace of `remoteIp` or `remoteAddr` inside it.